# Does Modernizr brings bad programming practises in web development?

Tags: javascript, html, css, modernizr

There are a lot of "buts" in approaches to web development. Recently I've read an article 
[why not to use Twitter bootstrap](http://www.zingdesign.com/5-reasons-not-to-use-twitter-bootstrap/). One of the reasons were that **it doesn’t follow best practices**. Well I don't want to discuss about TB. What I wanna know is how is it with **Modernizr** - it looks like that has a lot of advantages, but what about dissadvantages? Is that also redeemed by using bad programming practises on web (like these mentioned in twitter bootstrap)?
**By good practices I mean ideas which are connected with Html5 and CSS** => this is **not opinion based** question - I'm basicly asking if Modernizr is in contrary with these ideas.

Comment: Btw this is not a good question for StackOverflow because it is primarily opinion based, so I voted to close.

Comment: @elclanrs My question istn't about How to be good programmer. I din't wrote anything about that. Only oppinion based thing here are your comments, cause you didn't read the question properly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Modernizr itself tries to follow best practices as best as possible, however there are a few things that it does that aren't necessarily "best practice"

1. **it basically requires being loading in the `<head>`.** Since one of the main uses of Modernizr is the css classes that are added, you actually *want* it to block the rendering of the page until after it has ran. If you load it in the bottom of the page (which is the "best practice" for javascript, generally) and rely on the classes it provides, you would see a flicker between the non-support and support versions of your styles as it runs.
2. **It can be heavy**. There are ongoing discussions on the github issue tracker about how we can improve the execution time of the library, as well as [new preposed updates](https://github.com/Modernizr/Modernizr/issues/1246) to the lib that would group tests to increase speed

Not only that, but it can be used poorly. One of the most common issues is that people deploy their public website with the debug build of Modernizr - the one that includes ALL of the tests. This means running very large amount of javascript that never impacts your site.

Other than that, modernizr tries very hard to help *define* best practices, let alone just follow them. If you ever find there is any issue what so ever, I would really encourage you to open up an issue on [the github repo](http://github.com/Modernizr/Modernizr) to help us move the internet forward.